# Spark Dataframe Scala: groupby doesn't work after UnionAll

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I used `unionAll` to combine the source DF (with negative weights) and the target DF (with positive weights) into a node DF. Then I perform `groupby` to sum all the weights of the same nodes, but i don't know why `groupby` didn't work for the unioned DF at all. Did anyone face the same problem ?:

```
val src    = file.map(_.split("\t")).map(p => node(p(0), (0-p(2).trim.toInt))).toDF()
val target = file.map(_.split("\t")).map(p => node(p(1), p(2).trim.toInt)).toDF()

val srcfl = src.filter(src("weight") != -1)
val targetfl = target.filter(target("weight") != 1)

val nodes = srcfl.unionAll(targetfl)

nodes.groupBy("name").sum()

nodes.map(x => x.mkString("\t")).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:8020" + args(1))
```

Comment: plaase share example data, your code is not reproducible.

Answer (score 2):

You're simply ignoring the result of the `groupBy` operation: just like all DataFrame transformations, `.groupBy(...).sum()` doesn't **mutate** the original DataFrame (`nodes`), it produces a new one. I suspect that if you actually use the return value from `sum()` you'll see the result you're looking for:

```
val result = nodes.groupBy("name").sum()

result.map(x => x.mkString("\t")).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:8020" + args(1))
```